# PhoneGap Application - Images are blurry

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with images in my PhoneGap application. The icon images appear blurry; How can I resolve this issue?

[image: Blurry Icons]

This is my CSS

```
#login input:first-child { background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0) url(../images/holo_dark/hdpi/5_content_email.png) no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use images with better resolution?

Comment: test them on chrome or safari(or any other webkit-based browser and tell me the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest make icons according to DPI in android. Like samsung s2 has 1.5 dpi so we have to take the icon 1.5 times bigger than normal and adjust the icon by -webkit-background-size.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest doubling the size of the image to larger then needed. Then set CSS rule to half it. This will cover if your screen is larger then the standard 72ppi.